# While loop with a short statement

Tags: go, while-loop

I am quite new to Go and I already had a few occasions where I would like to use something like a while loop with a short statement (see examples below). Is something like that possible? I am pretty sure there must be some simple way to accomplish this but I was unable to find anything on the internet.

Examples:
(NOTE: I am aware the syntax in these examples isn't supported by Go, I just used the same syntax as in [if with a short statement](https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/6) to illustrate my issue)

```
// pop from queue until it returns nil
for val := queue.Pop(); val != nil {

}
```

```
// scan numbers until EOF (enough to check if err is nil for competitive programming)
var n int
for _, err := fmt.Scan(&n); err != nil {

}
```

Comment: `for val := queue.Pop(); val != nil; { }` The semicolon is required even if the post statement is empty!

Comment: @icza Yeah I know it compiles that way, but it doesn't work as I want. It executes the first statement only once before the loop

Comment: The init statement is always only executed once. If you need it to execute before each iteration, use `for val := queue.Pop(); val != nil; val = queue.Pop() { }`

Comment: I edited the question to make it more valuable for other users (so it doesn't look like a simple typo at first glance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not syntax for doing exactly what you want, but there's some options for expressing your intention relatively concisely.

Either you move the declaration inside the for loop:

```
for {
    val := queue.Pop()
    if val == nil { break }
    ...
}
```

Or you duplicate the expression:

```
for val := queue.Pop(); val != nil; val = queue.Pop() {
    ...
}
```

Or you express the loop condition differently (I'm guessing what `queue` is here, using `len` may not be the right way to find out if the queue is empty or not depending exactly what your queue type is).

```
for len(queue) > 0 {
   val := queue.Pop()
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was worried this would be the answer ... But nonetheless I am glad it is answered as I spent a good few minutes trying to find the answer through google

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful it is here, but the language spec is a good place to look for syntax problems -- it's a lot shorter and easier to read than most programming language specs. https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_statements